# Desafio JSON com JS

Tags: javascript, json

Tenho um arquivo esse arquivo  JS, preciso verificar os numeros que foram pulados na sequencia, separado por CNPJ,  como seria feito?

```js
[
{"cnpj":"1234567891011","serie":"1","numero":"1"},
{"cnpj":"1234567891011","serie":"1","numero":"2"},
{"cnpj":"1234567891011","serie":"1","numero":"3"},
{"cnpj":"1234567891011","serie":"1","numero":"4"},
{"cnpj":"1234567891011","serie":"1","numero":"5"},
{"cnpj":"1234567891011","serie":"1","numero":"6"},
{"cnpj":"1234567891011","serie":"1","numero":"7"},
{"cnpj":"1234567891011","serie":"1","numero":"9"},
{"cnpj":"1234567891011","serie":"1","numero":"10"},
{"cnpj":"1213141516171","serie":"1","numero":"1"},
{"cnpj":"1213141516171","serie":"1","numero":"2"},
{"cnpj":"1213141516171","serie":"1","numero":"4"},
{"cnpj":"1213141516171","serie":"1","numero":"5"},
{"cnpj":"1213141516171","serie":"1","numero":"6"},
{"cnpj":"1213141516171","serie":"1","numero":"7"},
{"cnpj":"1213141516171","serie":"1","numero":"9"},
{"cnpj":"1213141516171","serie":"2","numero":"10"},
{"cnpj":"1213141516171","serie":"2","numero":"11"},
{"cnpj":"1213141516171","serie":"2","numero":"12"},
{"cnpj":"1213141516171","serie":"2","numero":"15"},
{"cnpj":"1213141516171","serie":"2","numero":"16"},
{"cnpj":"1213141516171","serie":"2","numero":"17"},
{"cnpj":"1213141516171","serie":"2","numero":"21"},
{"cnpj":"9090909871234","serie":"1","numero":"22"},
{"cnpj":"9090909871234","serie":"1","numero":"1"},
{"cnpj":"9090909871234","serie":"1","numero":"2"},
{"cnpj":"9090909871234","serie":"1","numero":"3"},
{"cnpj":"9090909871234","serie":"1","numero":"4"},
{"cnpj":"9090909871234","serie":"1","numero":"6"},
{"cnpj":"9090909871234","serie":"1","numero":"7"},
{"cnpj":"9090909871234","serie":"1","numero":"8"},
{"cnpj":"9090909871234","serie":"3","numero":"2"},
{"cnpj":"9090909871234","serie":"3","numero":"1"},
{"cnpj":"9090909871234","serie":"3","numero":"3"},
{"cnpj":"9090909871234","serie":"3","numero":"4"},
{"cnpj":"9090909871234","serie":"3","numero":"5"},
{"cnpj":"9090909871234","serie":"3","numero":"6"},
{"cnpj":"9090909871234","serie":"3","numero":"7"},
{"cnpj":"9090909871234","serie":"3","numero":"8"},
{"cnpj":"9090909871234","serie":"3","numero":"9"},
{"cnpj":"9090909871234","serie":"3","numero":"10"},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode organizar o seu `array` inicial com a função `reduce` transformando em um objeto com seus respectivos itens. Depois disso percorra seu objeto organizado descobrindo o mínimo e o máximo. Tendo isso, filtre os números desse intervalo verificando quais não estão no seu `array` original:

```js
const dados = [
  { cnpj: '1234567891011', serie: '1', numero: '1' },
  { cnpj: '1234567891011', serie: '1', numero: '2' },
  { cnpj: '1234567891011', serie: '1', numero: '3' },
  { cnpj: '1234567891011', serie: '1', numero: '4' },
  { cnpj: '1234567891011', serie: '1', numero: '5' },
  { cnpj: '1234567891011', serie: '1', numero: '6' },
  { cnpj: '1234567891011', serie: '1', numero: '7' },
  { cnpj: '1234567891011', serie: '1', numero: '9' },
  { cnpj: '1234567891011', serie: '1', numero: '10' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '1', numero: '1' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '1', numero: '2' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '1', numero: '4' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '1', numero: '5' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '1', numero: '6' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '1', numero: '7' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '1', numero: '9' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '2', numero: '10' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '2', numero: '11' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '2', numero: '12' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '2', numero: '15' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '2', numero: '16' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '2', numero: '17' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '2', numero: '21' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '1', numero: '22' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '1', numero: '1' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '1', numero: '2' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '1', numero: '3' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '1', numero: '4' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '1', numero: '6' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '1', numero: '7' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '1', numero: '8' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '3', numero: '2' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '3', numero: '1' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '3', numero: '3' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '3', numero: '4' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '3', numero: '5' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '3', numero: '6' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '3', numero: '7' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '3', numero: '8' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '3', numero: '9' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '3', numero: '10' }
];

const organizados = dados.reduce((acumulador, { cnpj, numero }) => {
  const copia = { ...acumulador };
  copia[cnpj] = [...(copia[cnpj] || []), parseInt(numero, 10)];
  return copia;
}, {});

const faltando = Object.keys(organizados).reduce((acumulador, cnpj) => {
  const numeros = organizados[cnpj];
  const [minimo, maximo] = [Math.min(...numeros), Math.max(...numeros)];
  const copia = { ...acumulador };
  copia[cnpj] = Array.from(Array(maximo-minimo), (v, indice) => indice + minimo).filter(item => !numeros.includes(item));
  return copia;
}, {});

console.log('CNPJs organizados: ', JSON.stringify(organizados));
console.log('Números faltando: ', JSON.stringify(faltando));
```

---

> [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
>
> O método `reduce()` executa uma função `reducer` (provida por você) para cada membro do array, resultando num único valor de retorno.
>
> **Exemplo:**
>
> ```js
> const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
> const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
>
> // 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
> // expected output: 10
>
> // 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));
> // expected output: 15
> ```

Comment: se eu quiser separar por série os números que estão faltando, série 1: 3,4 , série 2: 5 , série 3: 3,6,7

Comment: @MarcosPaulo aí complica bastante... tem como fazer outra pergunta pra isso?

Comment: posso sim, vou faze-lá agora