# Ler JSON com JS

Tags: javascript, json

tenho o seguinte código

```js
const dados = [
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "1" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "2" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "3" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "4" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "5" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "6" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "7" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "9" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "10" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "1", "numero": "1" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "1", "numero": "2" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "1", "numero": "4" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "1", "numero": "5" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "1", "numero": "6" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "1", "numero": "7" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "1", "numero": "9" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "2", "numero": "10" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "2", "numero": "11" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "2", "numero": "12" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "2", "numero": "15" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "2", "numero": "16" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "2", "numero": "17" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "2", "numero": "21" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "3", "numero": "2" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "3", "numero": "3" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "3", "numero": "5" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "3", "numero": "6" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "3", "numero": "7" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "22" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "1" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "2" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "3" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "4" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "6" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "7" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "8" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "2" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "1" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "3" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "4" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "5" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "6" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "7" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "8" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "9" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "10" }
];

const organizados = dados.reduce((acumulador, { cnpj, numero }) => { 
  const copia = { ...acumulador };
  copia[cnpj] = [...(copia[cnpj] || []), parseInt(numero, 10)];
  return copia;
}, {});

const faltando = Object.keys(organizados).reduce((acumulador, cnpj) => { 
  const numeros = organizados[cnpj];
  const [minimo, maximo] = [Math.min(...numeros), Math.max(...numeros)];
  const copia = { ...acumulador };
  copia[cnpj] = Array.from(Array(maximo - minimo), (v, indice) => indice + minimo).filter(item => !numeros.includes(item));
  return copia;
}, {});

const imprime = (valores) => {                      
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(valores)) {
    console.log('Cliente:', key);
    let serie1 = [], serie2 = [], serie3 = [];
    for (let [k, v, s] of Object.entries(value)) {
      serie1.push(k);
      serie2.push(v);
      serie3.push(s);
    }
    console.log('Serie 1:', serie1.join(', '));
    console.log('serie 2:', serie2.join(', '));
    console.log('serie 3:', serie3.join(', '));
  }
}


console.log('pulou numeros');
imprime(faltando);
```

que verifica onde pulou o número separado por CNPJ e série, o problema é que não está puxando as série de número 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajustando a resposta da pergunta [**Desafio JSON com JS**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/369859/59479) para trabalhar com as séries na chave termos o seguinte:

```js
const dados = [
  { cnpj: '1234567891011', serie: '1', numero: '1' },
  { cnpj: '1234567891011', serie: '1', numero: '2' },
  { cnpj: '1234567891011', serie: '1', numero: '3' },
  { cnpj: '1234567891011', serie: '1', numero: '4' },
  { cnpj: '1234567891011', serie: '1', numero: '5' },
  { cnpj: '1234567891011', serie: '1', numero: '6' },
  { cnpj: '1234567891011', serie: '1', numero: '7' },
  { cnpj: '1234567891011', serie: '1', numero: '9' },
  { cnpj: '1234567891011', serie: '1', numero: '10' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '1', numero: '1' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '1', numero: '2' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '1', numero: '4' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '1', numero: '5' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '1', numero: '6' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '1', numero: '7' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '1', numero: '9' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '2', numero: '10' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '2', numero: '11' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '2', numero: '12' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '2', numero: '15' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '2', numero: '16' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '2', numero: '17' },
  { cnpj: '1213141516171', serie: '2', numero: '21' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '1', numero: '22' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '1', numero: '1' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '1', numero: '2' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '1', numero: '3' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '1', numero: '4' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '1', numero: '6' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '1', numero: '7' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '1', numero: '8' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '3', numero: '2' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '3', numero: '1' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '3', numero: '3' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '3', numero: '4' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '3', numero: '5' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '3', numero: '6' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '3', numero: '7' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '3', numero: '8' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '3', numero: '9' },
  { cnpj: '9090909871234', serie: '3', numero: '10' }
];

const organizados = dados.reduce((acumulador, { cnpj, serie, numero }) => {
  const copia = { ...acumulador };
  const chave = `${cnpj}-${serie}`;
  copia[chave] = [...(copia[chave] || []), parseInt(numero, 10)];
  return copia;
}, {});

const faltando = Object.keys(organizados).reduce((acumulador, chave) => {
  const numeros = organizados[chave];
  const [minimo, maximo] = [Math.min(...numeros), Math.max(...numeros)];
  const copia = { ...acumulador };
  copia[chave] = Array.from(Array(maximo-minimo), (v, indice) => indice + minimo).filter(item => !numeros.includes(item));
  return copia;
}, {});

console.log('CNPJs organizados:', JSON.stringify(organizados));
console.log('Números faltando:', JSON.stringify(faltando));
```

Comment: perfeito, só faltou a formatação, mas dou um jeito aqui

Comment: Como faria para dar uma quebra de linha?

Comment: CNPJ: 1234567891011
Série 1: 19
Série 2: 13, 18, 19, 20

Answer (score 0):

Voce gostaria de organizar as series de acordo com o atributo "serie" do seu array de objetos?

creio que pode ser resolvido da seguinte maneira:

```js
const dados = [
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "1" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "2" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "3" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "4" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "5" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "6" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "7" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "9" },
  { "cnpj": "1234567891011", "serie": "1", "numero": "10" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "1", "numero": "1" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "1", "numero": "2" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "1", "numero": "4" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "1", "numero": "5" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "1", "numero": "6" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "1", "numero": "7" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "1", "numero": "9" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "2", "numero": "10" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "2", "numero": "11" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "2", "numero": "12" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "2", "numero": "15" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "2", "numero": "16" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "2", "numero": "17" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "2", "numero": "21" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "3", "numero": "2" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "3", "numero": "3" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "3", "numero": "5" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "3", "numero": "6" },
  { "cnpj": "1213141516171", "serie": "3", "numero": "7" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "22" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "1" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "2" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "3" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "4" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "6" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "7" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "1", "numero": "8" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "2" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "1" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "3" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "4" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "5" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "6" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "7" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "8" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "9" },
  { "cnpj": "9090909871234", "serie": "3", "numero": "10" }
];
const distinctCnpj = [...new Set(dados.map(d => d.cnpj))];
const distinctSerie = [...new Set(dados.map(d => d.serie))];

const filterDados = {};

for(let c of distinctCnpj){
 filterDados[c] = []
  for(let s of distinctSerie){
  filterDados[c][s] = dados.filter(d => d.cnpj === c && d.serie === s).map(x => x.numero);
  }
}

const imprime = (valores) => {                      
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(valores)) {
    console.log('Cliente:', key);
    for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(value)) {
     console.log(`Serie ${k}: `, v.join(', '));
    }
  }
}

imprime(filterDados);
```

Comment: Seu código não funciona `dados is not defined`

Comment: não funcionou pois não tem o array

Comment: Segue a correção, que no caso era so pegar o array da pergunta.

Comment: está perfeito, mas não está mostrando a numeração que pulou, só está listando os numeros

Comment: Basta adicionar a condição para exibir.